# GIT confusion with the head

Tags: git

I'm a little be confused with branch in git.

Basically I start my project with a branch DEV. From this branch I have created other branch Like "Branch.1".

I have pushed with command git push origin Branch.1 and now I see the the Head of the tree is Branch.1 .

If I merge this branch with DEV can I do that the head is DEV? Or how can I do to have the branch DEV like the head? (Without loosing the modify that I have done in Branch.1)

Thank you so much.

Comment: You always merge *into* the current branch, you can't merge "outwards". If you want to merge *to* DEV, you have to be *on* DEV. I don't know exactly what you mean by "the modify that I have done in Branch 1" so I cannot comment on how this affects it.

Comment: If you push the brach "Branch.1", now it has the last changed for aligning the change with the dev branch you must be create a pull-request for join the branch 1 with the branch dev

Comment: Ok, the problem is that if I pass in DEV branch I lost what I wrote in Branch.1 ( this is what I mean with "the modify that I have done in Branch.1")

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo So you suggest to go in Branch.1 branch and do: 
git pull origin DEV ?

Comment: @Jack23 you can use the [pull-request](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) from "branch1" to "branch dev"

Comment: Ok (I don't want make mistake :) ) So I'm in the branch.1 and I do: 
"git request-pull branch.1 DEV " right?

Comment: @Jack23 yes, if I have a little time, I will write an answer with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch can be joined with the operation [pull-request](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull), with this is possible to join the changes inside a branch, so I do an example

You have a branch **DEV** and a branch **Branch.1**, you work in the **Branch.1**, and to end work, want to marge the code inside the branch **DEV**, you can this operation with the terminal with this code

```
git request-pull Branch.1 origin DEV
```

Everything will be successful if there are no conflicts in the code.